# C++ 11 thread simple example

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, iostream

I'm new to c++ and I was looking into some c++ cross-platform thread tutorials. I was looking into this: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

and was trying to execute the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

static const int num_threads = 10;

//This function will be called from a thread

void call_from_thread(int tid) {
    std::cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t[num_threads];

    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
    }

    std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";

    //Join the threads with the main thread
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is the following and I can not understand why:

```
syd@syd-HP-Compaq-dx7500-Microtower:~/Desktop$ ./ref
Launched by thread Launched by thread Launched by thread Launched by thread Launched by thread 201
Launched by thread 5

Launched by thread 6
4
Launched by thread 7
3

Launched by thread 8
Launched from the main
Launched by thread 9
```

I understand that the numbers are random each time, but some times I get no numbers displayed and I wonder why?

Comment: There's no line-by-line or `operator<<`-call synchronization of `std::cout << "something"`. That's why the output of several threads can be interleaved.

Comment: To be more precise, the C++ Standard specifies for the standard streams in [iostreams.objects.overview]/4 "Concurrent access to a synchronized standard iostream object’s formatted and unformatted input and output functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result
in a data race. [*Note:* Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by
multiple threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. — *end note* ]"

Comment: Something like  std::string str =  "Launched by thread " then
str.append(tid) and **then** print it would work fine

Comment: Std::cout is useless when using multiple threads, printf might help

Comment: @James: Not completely useless, just slightly inconvenient, forcing you to format a whole line (or however much you want grouped together) as a single string before streaming it. `printf` might be more convenient, if you don't care about type safety or support for user-defined types.

Comment: @LanPac: That's not guaranteed either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're all there. They're just mangled up because the console output happens in vaguely random orders.

In particular have a look at the end of the first line of output.

Answer (score 17):

all you need to do is adding a mutex and lock it in the proper position:

```
std::mutex mtx;
```

-

```
void call_from_thread(int tid) {
    mtx.lock();
-----------------------------------------------------------
    std::cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl;
-----------------------------------------------------------
    mtx.unlock();
}
```

-

```
mtx.lock();
-----------------------------------------------------------
std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";
-----------------------------------------------------------
mtx.unlock();
```

[refer to this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/C11/7_C11_Thread_Sharing_Memory.php)

Answer (score 3):

There is a race condition in IO(cout) in

```
std::cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl;
```

Actually, there is no guaranty to cout ("Launched by thread", tid, std::endl) sequencing. And it behaves like this:

```
std::cout << "Launched by thread " ;
cout<< tid ;
cout<< std::endl;
```

You can change **call_from_thread** to :

```
void call_from_thread(int tid) {
    std::cout << std::string("Launched by thread " + std::to_string(tid) + "\n");
}
```

The next point is in

```
t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
```

When you create a thread, at creation time the function **call_from_thread** will be called.

So It is better to move

```
std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";
```

Before

```
//Launch a group of threads
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
    t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
}
```

You also can use [holders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
mutex g_i_mutex;  // protects cout

void call_from_thread(int tid) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
    cout << "Launched by thread " ;
    cout<< tid ;
    cout<< std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Flushing stream should do the trick :)

Following line: `std::cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl;`

Change to: `std::cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl << std::flush;`